# How to select sibling input fields inside Kendo Grid Popup Editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm wondering how I can fill Age textbox with calculated value, if BirthDate is changed.

Please do not worry about Birth Date to Age calculation; I just want to know how to apply value from one textbox to another.

***Note:*** I'm working on Angular Kendo. I'll be more than happy, if there is a better method for Angular specific.

http://jsfiddle.net/h53gewka/

[image]

```
edit: function(e) {
  $(e.container).find("input[name='BirthDate']")                 
     .data("kendoDatePicker").bind("change", function(e) {
        console.log("Birth Date is changed!");
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure it is a correct approach in term of AngularJs.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9cwga27/

```
edit: function(e) {
    $(e.container)
        .find("input[name='BirthDate']")
        .data("kendoDatePicker")
        .bind("change", function(e) {
            this.element.closest("[data-role=window]")
            .find("input[name=Age]")
            .data("kendoNumericTextBox")
            .value(123);                            
        });
},
```